# Symfony2 another Entity in Formbuilder

Tags: symfony, entity, formbuilder

i got a problem / understanding problem.

**I have 3 db tables**
user, usergroup and user2usergroup

**the foreign fields:**
user.id => user2usergroup.user_id
user2usergroup.group_id => usergroup.id

So now i want to generate and edit my user object and get the relationship to my formbuilder.

I tried some ideas and researched for help.

Not this is the acutal state:

controller:

```
/**
 * creates user form
 * @param users $entity
 * @param string $sUrl
 * @return Form
 */
public function createUserForm(users $entity, $sUrl){
    $form = $this->createForm(new userType(), $entity, array(
        'action'    => $this->generateUrl($sUrl),
        'method'    => 'POST',
        'groups'    => $this->getUserGroups()
    ));
    return $form;
}
```

formbuilder

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $groups = $options['groups'];

    $builder
        ->add('enabled','checkbox',array(
                'required'  => false))
        ->add('locked','checkbox',array(
                'required'  => false))
        ->add('username','text',array(
                'required'  => true))
        ->add('email','email',array(
                'required'  => true))
        ->add('password','password',array(
                'required'  => true))
        ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
                    'choices'  => array('ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Admin', 'ROLE_USER' => 'Benutzer'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'multiple' => true
                ))
        ->add('groups','entity',array(
            'class' => 'UniteUserBundle:usergroup',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                    return $er->findAll();
                },

        ))
        ->add('save','submit')
        ;

}
```

Maybe you can help me to understand 
- how to get all groups to the form
- how to edit the user and see which groups he is in (edit view)
- how i can persist the groups i selected in the user form to the user2usergroup

Thanks a lot my friends =)

Answer (score 0):

To show the groups where a user belongs to is not to difficult:

```
{% for usergroup in entity.getUserGroups() %}
    <li>{{ usergroup.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

To edit them in a USER form is more complicated since you are editing one user but this user can be in zero, one or multiple groups. That means that each group in the list could be edited and deleted and that you can add a new group.

For this situation you can use the [**Collection field type**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). In [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) you can read step by step how to use it.

Comment: Hey again, i want to edit and add the groups with another form. I just want to add a user, and add groups to him (select this groups). Than i wanted to add the connection in the table user2usergroup. The other question, how did i get the connections of user 2 groups. ====== am i wrong? Should i just add the roles as an array to the database user? and dont write it to an extra table with all the connections between user and groups?

Comment: Uhm first things first. Roles got nothing to do with groups. That are totally different things. For the relation between groups and users you can choose for a manyToMany relation. Doctine is able to automatically create and fill the jointable. See this example: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional and do not forget to insert ORM\ after the @ in the annotations. manyToMany will say that each user can belong to multiple groups and each group can have multiple users. Do not store array's into the database.

Comment: Sorry i meant group not roles. I got it now. I'm using FOSUserBundle. Now i got the problem, how to persist the group to the user when i add and edit the user. Thansk for your help :)

Comment: Scroll a bit downwards from this chapter and read about Doctrine: Cascading Relations and saving the "Inverse" side. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype

Comment: Hey Frankbeen, i read this chapter. This is not wat i meant. I want to persist a user to a group with a manytomany connection. The main problem is, i tried to load it in my userType via collection, but i don't get an output to my form.